# Blocking Watcher users

Tags: python, mysql, curl

Good afternoon Help me complete the script for blocking Watcher users.
The script scrapes the database from our user (login and blocking) and pulls users out of Watcher with a curl. Each user's logins, so I decided to just compare the logins and check the blocking status.
In our billing, if a user has no money on his balance, he is blocked, so when he logs into the system, the blocking status is “blocked”, we simply disconnect the user in Watcher.

```
import os
import pymysql.cursors
import json
import re

i = 0
connection = pymysql.connect(host = '****',
                            database = '***',
                            user = 'login',
                            password = 'password')

Login_internetQ = "SELECT login, blocked FROM clients_internet"
os.system('curl -o output.json -X GET "http://89.249.128.55/vsaas/api/v2/users?limit=1000" -H "x-vsaas-api-key:API"')

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   cursor.execute(Login_internetQ)
   result = cursor.fetchall()`
   for row in result:
      `print(row[0],row[1])
with open('output.json') as file:
   watcher_base = json.load(file)
print(type(watcher_base))
print(type(watcher_base[0]))
print(watcher_base)

while i != 76:
   memory = watcher_base[i]
   user_id_watcher = memory['id']
   login_watcher = memory['login']
   print(user_id_watcher, login_watcher, row[0], row[1])
   if (row[0] == login_watcher and row[1] > 0):
      one = os.system('curl  -sf -X PUT "http://89.249.128.55/vsaas/api/v2/users/) + (user_id_watcher) + (" -H "x-vsaas-session:API" -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{ "enabled": "false"}"')
      print(one)
      print(login_watcher, 'заблокирован')
   else:
      if (row[0] == login_watcher and row[1] == 0):
         two = os.system('curl -sf -X PUT "http://89.249.128.55/vsaas/api/v2/users/) + (user_id_watcher) + (" -H "x-vsaas-session:API" -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{ "enabled": "true"}"')
         print(two)
         print(login_watcher, 'разблокирован')
      else:
         print(login_watcher, 'не достаточно средств для разблокировки')
   i += 1
```

I unload subscribers from the database, and unload users from Watcher. At the time of comparing logins, for some reason all the logins from the watcher are compared only with the last login from the billing
But even if this is not taken into account, curl does not work to block and unblock the user in watcher

Comment: `row` is set when you loop over the cursor resultset. Thus it will always be the last row in the resultset.